# I am getting a unexpected error with loops

Tags: javascript, loops

```
function setL(sname, svalue) {
    localStorage.setItem(sname, svalue)
}

function getL(sname) {
    if (!localStorage.getItem(sname)) localStorage.setItem(sname, "")
    return localStorage.getItem(sname)
}

function delL(sname) {
    localStorage.removeItem(sname)
}


for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (getL(options[i]) == null) {} else {
        $("#" + options[i]).attr("value", getL(options[i]));
        $(options_target[i]).css(options_change[i], getL(options[i]));
    }
};
```

`getL` get's value from `localstorage`. so what my loop does is, for

```
  var options = ["bg_color", "bottom_bar_color", "button_color", "dialog_color", "notify_color", "button_text_color"];
  var options_target = ["body", "#bottom", ".ugly-button", ".dialog", ".notification .notification-body", ".ugly-button"];
  var options_change = ["background", "background", "background", "background", "color"];
```

it sets the appropriate css value for the appropriate element using the "options" array's value's which were set as localstorage..

this used to work a day ago.. but now i am getting a unexpected error..which is

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

there is no replace in my code so can anyone help me debug the code and fix it if possible?

Comment: Possible error could be on getL() or css(); Could you please post getL();

Comment: Show code of `getL()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var options = ["bg_color", "bottom_bar_color", "button_color", "dialog_color", "notify_color", "button_text_color"];
  var options_target = ["body", "#bottom", ".ugly-button", ".dialog", ".notification .notification-body", ".ugly-button"];
  var options_change = ["background", "background", "background", "background", "color"];
```

options length is 6. 
options_target length is 7. 
options_change length is 5.

So: i goes from 0 to 5.

```
$(options_target[i]).css(options_change[i], getL(options[i]));
```

When i is 5:
options[i] has value, options_change[i] is undefined, because it is out of range...

Comment: oh okay so my clumsiness was the error.. thanks for your help!

Comment: Yeah that was the problem.. thanks for helping! really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

<strike>JQuery `1.6.4` runs your code fine.</strike>

## [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yn788m0s/)

JQuery `2.1.3` however, gives the above error.

## [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/f699onw7/)

If you have indeed updated JQuery recently, that might very well be your issue.

## EDIT

That's odd that it worked with an earlier JQuery, because your error is that your last list is of a different length than the previous two. Thus, when looping over the first list, you try to access an inde of `options_change` that doesn't exist. Try `push`ing `"color"`, for example, to `options_change` and it works fine:

```
var options = ["bg_color","bottom_bar_color","button_color","dialog_color","notify_color","button_text_color"];
 var options_target = ["body","#bottom",".ugly-button",".dialog",".notification .notification-body",".ugly-button"];
var options_change = ["background","background","background","background","color", "color"]; 
function setL(sname, svalue) {
localStorage.setItem(sname, svalue)
}
function getL(sname) {
if(!localStorage.getItem(sname)) localStorage.setItem(sname, "")
return localStorage.getItem(sname)
} 
function delL(sname) {
localStorage.removeItem(sname)
}


for(i = 0; i < options.length;i++){
if(getL(options[i]) == null){
} else {
$("#" + options[i]).attr("value" , getL(options[i]) );       
$(options_target[i]).css(options_change[i] , getL(options[i]) );
}
};

alert("No Errors!");
```

## [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0je218en/)

Comment: yes thanks for the example's and explaining to me what was wrong! i really appreciate it!